# SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .Net Data Provider, reason code 8

Tags: db2

I am trying to run a local code built in .net and after parsing through many errors like reason code 10 and 3. I am stuck at **RC 8**

It gives the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection' threw an exception.
  Source=IBM.Data.DB2
  TypeName=IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection
  StackTrace:
       at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
       at MoreM3.DataAccess.Model.DB2DataProvider.CreateConnection(String connectionString) in C:\M3\MOREM3\Trunk\MOREM3\MoreM3.DataAccess\Model\DB2DataProvider.cs:line 11
       at MoreM3.DataAccess.Model.DB2DataProvider.CreateConnection() in C:\M3\MOREM3\Trunk\MOREM3\MoreM3.DataAccess\Model\DB2DataProvider.cs:line 17
       at MoreM3.DataAccess.StatusDB.LoadOpenStatusesForAssociate(Int32 storeNumber, Int32 associateEmployeeID) in C:\M3\MOREM3\Trunk\MOREM3\MoreM3.DataAccess\StatusDB.cs:line 462
       at MoreM3.MyPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\M3\MOREM3\Trunk\MOREM3\MOREM3\MyPage.aspx.cs:line 53
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=SQL1159  Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 8, tokens 0, 120, 112
       Source=IBM.Data.DB2
       StackTrace:
            at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.i()
            at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool..ctor()
            at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

**Note**: Googling the reason code 8, I found it says structure mismatch between native and managed code.

Comment: Same problem. Tried with both nupkg for 11.1.3 DB2 and installed 64-bit data client. Same error. Can not parallel install 32-bit, but process runs anyway in 64-bit host process.

Comment: Reason code 8 is allegedly 32/64 bit difference.